# Linux Foundation Acumos AI Project

Tags: artificial-intelligence, acumos

When using Acumos AI platform, it seems I cannot on-board my AI/ML models to Acumos site directly, is this correct? If yes, what is the right process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, onboarding your models directly to Acumos.org is currently disabled for security reasons. However, you can download and setup your own Acumos instance and share models to/from Acumos.org via the backend federation function. Please see https://wiki.acumos.org/ for more information.